# Add a border around an element with text

Tags: css

I have tried to reduce source to something more manageable (hopefully) to here..

https://jsfiddle.net/pa9uLej4/1/

It currently looks pretty plain but it's actually a rectangle. What I want to do is add a colored border that wraps around the rectangle where the text "Footer" is within that colored region. The three words above the footer are within the rectangle but that area is not colored.

I tried wrapping everything with a div and class `email-wrapper` and added `background-color: #aaaaaa` but it does nothing.

Hopefully that's clear. Anyone able to help?

Comment: Did you want something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cp4n7u6s/?

Comment: can you please add a screenshot. thanks

Comment: your background color is not working because you have given color to your table that is overlapping

Comment: Please remove CSS (background-color:#ffffff;) from table tag.

Comment: I'll try removing that background color. Aniket, no not around just the footer. I want the area around the rectangle to have color and that area to also include the footer word. It wraps around the entire div which is what i was trying to do with email-wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this out and let me know.
[codepen](https://codepen.io/naveensfiddle/pen/BEQMBW)!

```css
#content {
  border: 2px solid #999;
  border-top: 20px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
}

.titlebox {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0px;
  margin: -28px 0 0 30px;
  background: #999;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="titlebox">Vocabularies</div>
    <p>This is a div</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is closer to what I want. Perhaps border is throwing people off but I wanted that color gray to be wider and "Vocabularies" to have a background of gray too. So it's a part of the shaded area

Comment: Hello @pad11 I have altered my solution please run the snippet and let me know. I would rather suggest you to use 2 divisions instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to add border like your way you can give padding to the .email-wrapper  and give background color.

```css
body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.table-wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
}

.email-wrapper {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  padding:5px;
}

table.body-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.8;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container {
  display: block !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  /* makes it centered */
  clear: both !important;
}

.header {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  height: 80px;
  background: {
      {
      email_settings.brand_primary
    }
  }
  ;
  background-size: 300px;
  background-position: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  line-height: 55px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: {
      {
      email_settings.brand_navbar_text
    }
  }
  ;
}

.header-title {
  background: {
      {
      email_settings.brand_primary
    }
  }
  ;
  color: {
      {
      email_settings.brand_navbar_text
    }
  }
  ;
  padding: 0px 60px 40px;
  text-align: center;
    {
    % if email_settings.brand_primary=="#ffffff" %
  }
  padding-bottom: 0px;
    {
    % endif %
  }
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.header-title h1,
.header-title h1 a {
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: {
      {
      email_settings.brand_navbar_text
    }
  }
  ;
}

.content .header-title h1:first-child {
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.header-title p,
.header-title p a {
  color: {
      {
      email_settings.brand_navbar_text
    }
  }
  ;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.header-margin-overide {
  margin-top: -40px;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  /* makes it centered */
  clear: both !important;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.content p,
.content h1,
.content h2,
.content table,
.content hr {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.content p:first-child,
.content h1 {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.content p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.condensed-width {
  max-width: 510px;
  margin: auto;
}

.footer {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666;
}

.data-table td {
  background: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 70px;
}

.data-table tr.bordered {
  border-top: 1px solid #B5C2D3;
}

.subtitle {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.small {
  font-size: 80%;
  line-height: 250%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.margin-none {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.padding-none {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p,
ul,
ol {
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7;
  margin-bottom: 1.3em;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #47505E;
}

p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

ul li,
ol li {
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.content h1.headline:first-child,
.content h2.headline:first-child {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.content h2.subline {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 700px) {
  .table-wrapper {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
  }
  .header {
    border-radius: 0px !important;
  }
  .header-title {
    padding-left: 20px !important;
    padding-right: 20px !important;
  }
  .header-title h1 {
    font-size: 25px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="email-wrapper">
    <table style="background: #ffffff;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table-wrapper">
            <tr>
              <td class="container header">
                <p>
                  "test"
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: I'll mess around with this but what i ultimately want is a border that wraps around the div but also have "Footer" text within that border. So if the border was colored grey, I could see the Footer text within that with a background of grey.